# Confirm that Batarang is broken

Tags: javascript, angularjs

[Not just me saying](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-batarang/ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk/reviews?hl=en)
I would like to share my recent experiences using Chrome 3.0 
debugging developer tools together with Batarang. After much struggle,
I am led to the conclusion that the recent claims on Batarang being broken
are true. As I have no previous Batarang experience, I did not know what to expect.
I am debugging angular jsfiddles.
I have found the source code in two separate areas as shown here:

[image: Where the source code is under resources]
[image: Where the source code is under sources]

I have at some point been able to view the child scope value for my 
hello world example but that stopped. Then it just would not open the link.

[image: Bug: Link for child scope 003 wont open and show]
Now it says no scope shown. While the console states it cannot get a connection it does report the child scope as 003.

[image: Console not getting a connection]

I was FINALLY lucky to noticed that the option at the left including angular 1.1.1
got changed to no library. I manually changed these back from no library
back to angular 1.1.1 only to see that it goes back to no library as soon 
as i run it with or without the debugger. That of course explains the fact 
that scope is not seen in batarang. But what is going on???

Lastly any changes made to gogirl input is ignored by the debugger but shows on the page. I am not sure if I am putting my breakpoints and watches correctly. Just in case, I am overlooking something...can someone pls see if my fiddle works on their machine with batarang?

[image: My setup]
here's the fiddle or use any hello world you have:[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gogirl/JmYT4/19/)

```
   <script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 

var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

//myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {});
//myApp.factory('myService', function() {});

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    debugger;
    $scope.name = 'gogirl';
    console.log($scope);
}
//]]>  

</script>
```

Comment: After scalaGirl worked so hard to put this complete question together, you are going to dismiss it so lazily?

Comment: Latest batarang is crap. Not usable at all. I am using ng-inspector

Comment: This was closed as too broad, then reopened, but honestly does anyone even know what the OP is asking? The title doesn't describe any remotely on-topic question for the site, and even if the OP put tons of effort into the actual post, if they meant to post a bug report then I'm sorry but this is simply not the right place.

Comment: It's broken as of today as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a working version of Angular Batarang you can go to their github repository and download the [released version](https://github.com/angular/angularjs-batarang/releases) that suits you most. For me, 0.4.3 is working fine. I was also disappointed when I updated my chrome extensions. Let me know how 0.4.3 works for you.